# How can I create a directive that will style data with transcluded HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have what I believe is a very simple desire for a directive: to take an array or object as a directive attribute and then allows the user of the directive to decide how to format/style the data (assume that the directive is more complex than I have outlined here and that it allows further manipulation of the data).

A non-functional example is as follows:

## The directive

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', () => {
  return {
    template: '<h2>Your data:</h2><div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: false,
    link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) => {
      $scope.people = $attrs.data;

      // Assume some processing on the people data can occur here
    },
    controller: ($scope, $element, $attrs) => {
      $scope.people = $attrs.data;

      // Also assume that it can happen here
    }
  };
});
```

## The view

```
<my-directive data="[{name: 'Tyler'}, {name: 'Mike'}, {name: 'John'}]">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</my-directive>
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why such a seemingly simple and contrived implementation wouldn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if `data` is a valid attribute name considering `data-*` attributes.

Comment: That actually hasn't affected me ever but I tested with a different name, locally, and the results were no different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup passed to ng-transclude is already parsed *before* it's transcluded into the directive. Meaning it's accessing things on the scope outside your directive only. Since you specified `scope: false` it's true that the directive shares the outer scope, however you don't define `scope.people` until the link or controller functions run which would be *after* the transcluded markup was transcluded.

Angular sets up a "transclusion scope" which initially inherits from the outer scope so you have access to things in that context. However, to avoid scopes not getting destroyed when the directive scope is destroyed Angular actually replaces `$parent` with the directive's isolate scope.

In other words, you should be able to access directive scope data via the `$parent` property.

```
<my-directive data="[{name: 'Tyler'}, {name: 'Mike'}, {name: 'John'}]">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in $parent.people">{{person.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</my-directive>
```

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/eJKBgj?editors=1010

Comment: Absolutely awesome answer! This is exactly the issue and makes a lot of sense as to why it's happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One thing i see you can do here is pass the data in through the directive's scope so it can be referenced as an object, not a string:

```
scope: {
  people: '='
},
```

then you can do all the manipulation you want to in the link/controller of your directive and it'll be reflected in the transcluded markup.

take a look at this plnkr for an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/XK8YlcdeZ26nkhyopLb1?p=preview

Comment: Great suggestion, however, I do want to avoid an isolate scope so that the transcluded HTML and the directive can share a scope.